# How to make inheritance on Odoo object

Tags: odoo, multiple-inheritance, odoo-12

I'm trying to add inheritance on existing object in Odoo, which is "mail.alias.mixin" into "utm.campaign" object.

I tried to do _inherit = ["mail.alias.mixin", "utm.campaign"] but when I install my module it always said

```
File "/home/randy/Odoo/odoo_12/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 180, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: None
```

Here is my code in full:

***manifest***.py

```
{
    "name": "CRM ext",
    "version": "12.4.0.0.0",
    'author': 'me',
    "description": """
    extend CRM.
    """,
    "depends": [
        'crm',
        'calendar',
        'fetchmail',
        'utm',
        'web_tour',
        'digest',
        'mail',
    ],
    'init_xml': [],
    'data': [
        "security/ir.model.access.csv",
        'data/crm_question.xml',
        'wizard/lost_and_link_partner_crm_wizard_views.xml',
        'views/crm_lead_view.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'active': False,
    'application': False,
}
```

And my utm.py

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, SUPERUSER_ID
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.tools import pycompat
from odoo.tools.safe_eval import safe_eval


class Campaign(models.Model):
    _name = "utm.campaign"
    _inherit = ["mail.alias.mixin", "utm.campaign"]

    alias_id = fields.Many2one('mail.alias', string='Alias', ondelete="restrict", required=True, help="The email address associated with this campaign. New emails received will automatically create new leads assigned to the campaign.")
    crm_team_id = fields.Many2one('crm.team', string="CRM Team")
```

I except that my inheritance is correct, but It seems that I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

According to Odoo 12 documentation you can inherit from multiple models only if _name is set. In your code _name is equal to parent model and that is same as not setting name. You're not defining new model so you can not inherit from multiple parents.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-inheritance

_inherit
If _name is set, names of parent models to inherit from. Can be a str if inheriting from a single parent
If _name is unset, name of a single model to extend in-place

Answer (score 0):

I found it,

So "mail.alias.mixin" are abstract object, I miss this one. So, I need to implement all the abstract method too.

Hope this can save someone's day!